# Possible to use USBTinyISP as an FTDI?

Tags: usb, avr, ftdi, isp

So, I have an atmega328p and I need to communicate with a computer from it, so I need an FTDI. However, all I have is a USBTinyISP. Is there some way I could hack something together so that I can use the FTDI in the USBTinyISP as a general FTDI without having to mess with the firmware of the USBTinyISP?

Comment: FTDI is just a brand, it is not a functiuonal description af a chip. I think you mean a USB-UART, USB-SPI or similar converter.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is serial communication with the computer then yes this can be done. However, if you need true FTDI functionality (i.e. using an FTDI driver on the computer etc.) then you need an FTDI chip.

For an example of serial communication to the computer using the SPI lines from the USBTinyISP see [here](http://blog.kehribar.me/?p=36). That should do for a basic FTDI serial comm port type interface, but like I said it is not actually an FTDI comm port emulator IC.

Comment: It's not out of the question that enough of the FTDI communication details could be emulated to achieve interoperability (at least with some drivers), though space on the MCU could be a limitation.  For the implied application though, alternative serial as mentioned should be fine, and easier to implement.

Comment: Looks like the link is broken. :(

Answer (score 0):

The USBTinyISP I can find (http://dicks.home.xs4all.nl/avr/usbtiny/) has not FTDI chip in it, so the answer is obviously NO.

Comment: Wow, you would be right. I wasn't aware a USB stack could be built on top of an ATTiny

Comment: This conclusion isn't really practically accurate, as the core functionality can be duplicated in software, perhaps even in a driver compatible way.